# How to show astronaut in python game

Tags: python, pygame, pgzero

I'm making code for a Python game and I have the following

```
WIDTH = 600
HEIGHT = 800
player_x = 600
player_y = 350
def draw():
    screen.blit(images.backdrop, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(images.mars, (50, 50))
    screen.blit(images.astronaut, (player_x, player_y))
    screen.blit(images.ship, (550, 300))
def game_loop():
    global player_x, player_y
    if keyboard.right:
        player_x += 5
    elif keyboard.left:
        player_x -= 5
    elif keyboard.up:
        player_y -= 5
    elif keyboard.down:
        player_y += 5
    clock.schedule_interval(game_loop, 0.03)
```

However, when I run it, it won't show the astronaut. I have the astronaut image for it but whatever I try doing, it will not work. Can someone please tell me where the problem is?

Comment: You're drawing the astronaut at x=600, and your width is apparently 600. Maybe try moving the astronaut a bit to the left to make sure they are onscreen.

Comment: What happens when you initialize the astronaut to be at e.g. `width//2` and `height//2` rather than at the edge of the screen (which your code is currently doing)?

Answer (score 2):

The coordinate which is passed to [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit), is the position of the top left corner of the surface. Since the width of the surface is 600 and the x coordinate is 600, the surface outside of the window on the right.
You can switch the x coordinate of the astronaut, but most likely the `WIDTH` and  `HEIGHT` of your window are switched:

<s>`WIDTH = 600`</s>
<s>`HEIGHT = 800`</s>

```py
WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600
```

Comment: Thanks for your input guys! I actually looked at my code and found out I switched my original width and height